# How can I implement non-Ext functionality in a page controlled by Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs

I'm adding several pieces of functionality to an existing Rails 4 app that uses Ext 3.2.

I'd like to have a section of the page where I can use jQuery, jQuery UI, and my own hand-written JS reliably, without interference from Ext.

## Attempt 1: `<script>` tag

I placed my JavaScript code directly into HTML within a `<script>` tag.

Here is a representative example very similar to the kind of code I'm trying to implement.

```
<script>
  (function () {

    /*
     * We bind the event handlers in a separate function so we can call it
     * when the DOM updates.
     * */
    var bindHandlers = function () {

      $('.action_button').click(function (event) {

        var obj_id = $(event.target).closest('.whatever').attr('data-obj-id');
        var url = '/something/' + obj_id;

        $.post(url, function (data) {
          // [...]
        });

        // [...]

      });

      $('.form_f_submit_button').click(function(event){
        $('form.door_form').submit();
      });

    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
      bindHandlers();
    });

  }());
</script>
```

When I do this, it works perfectly on my local dev machine, but only partially in production -- some functions work, others simply do nothing. For example `.action_button` may work, but not `.form_f_submit_button`.

I don't see any errors in the dev tools console.

## Attempt 2: separate JavaScript file

If I move my JS to a separate file and link to it, then nothing works at all locally or in production.

If I click on a button to which I've bound a function as you can see in the code above, absolutely nothing happens. No AJAX request occurs, and there's no output in the dev tools JS console. No errors. Nothing.

The page behaves exactly as though my JavaScript code didn't exist.

## General observations

It's clear that Ext is rewriting the DOM after page load.

Once the page is fully loaded, I view page source and some of the HTML elements are present, but about 95% is not visible in page source.

For instance I have a hand-coded HTML `<form>` with several fields inside an Ext panel. There's no sign of that in View Source.

If I examine the page structure in dev tools under the "Elements" tab, I find that my form **IS** there, along with everything else.

Based on that, what I think **seems** to be happening is that Ext is deleting the DOM, or most of it, and recreating it on the fly after page load.

If I examine a specific element in dev tools Elements tab, for example a field within my `<form>`, I find that it's **very** deeply nested within a structure of elements like this: `#ext-gen97 #ext-gen32 #ext-gen46` and so on.

I didn't code my HTML with things like `#ext-gen42`, but now they're present. So that's another reason I think Ext is deleting everything are rebuilding it.

I'm guessing maybe that's a basic part of how Ext works?

Ok, so if it's doing that, and if I have a `$(document).ready( //... )` function that binds some handlers to elements, then that could hint at why my handlers suddenly don't work as I described above. It could be that my handler binding JS is running before **Ext** recreates the DOM.

Do you see what I'm saying?

So in that case, they would have no effect. Maybe the elements my handlers got bound to were removed by Ext (and then, eventually restored, but then obviously after that nothing would be bound to them anymore.)

This is just a hypothesis based on what I observe here.

**Perhaps someone who understands Ext better could lend some insight.**

## The basic question

Aside from all that here's what I'm wondering:

1. Is there some way within Ext that I can designate a section of the page, like say one specific `<div>` or perhaps an `<iframe>` and say, "Hey Ext, just leave this bit alone. Don't erase it, don't rewrite it, don't nest it inside any `div#ext-gen264` elements. Just step aside and let me handle it."
2. Alternately, maybe there's to ensure that my code gets loaded **after** Ext does its thing. If I could ensure that somehow, then that could solve the problem.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1f53

Comment: There's not enough information here. There shouldn't be anything stopping you from running other scripts inside an Ext app.

Comment: Thanks Evan Trimboli, but are you sure? Because that isn't what I'm seeing my project here. Ext is definitely doing extensive DOM manipulation, and I could see how that could easily interfere with code outside Ext that binds functions to events on DOM elements. Could there be some caveat I need to be aware of? Like maybe is there some detail or workaround you need to apply in order to get non-Ext event handlers to work?

Comment: The short answer is there's nothing preventing them from working together. The long answer is you could be doing something to cause them to conflict, but without information it's not possible to say. Here's an example of Ext with jQuery: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1f3q

Comment: What further information in particular would be helpful? Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: You'll need to post a test case, it's not really feasible to enumerate all the possibilities. It sounds like you're doing some weird stuff, for example "For instance I have a hand-coded HTML <form> with several fields inside an Ext panel. There's no sign of that in View Source.". How are you hand coding a form inside an Ext Panel?

Comment: "How are you hand coding a form inside an Ext Panel?" With `contentEl`. "You'll need to post a test case" See link above.

Comment: Your fiddle has syntax errors in it, + it never loads jquery, and it doesn't run the Ext code in an onReady. I've fixed it up: https://jsfiddle.net/3hds1tts/